# In a Java 8 stream, how to filter out Strings that aren't valid values of an Enum?

Tags: java, exception, enums, java-stream, filtering

I have an **enum** I call `Permission` of security permissions that matter to my application.  In the database, the user may have additional permissions that are not relevant to my application.  When reading the user from the database, I get a `List<String>` and I want to build up a `List<Permission>`, ignoring those strings that aren't values of the enum.

```java
public enum Permission { ADMIN, USER }

List<String> plaintextAuthorities = List.of("ADMIN","USER","COFFEEMAKER")

List<Permission> appPermissions = plaintextAuthorities.stream()
        .map(Permission::valueOf) // this will throw an IllegalArgumentException for 'COFFEEMAKER'
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem is that the `map` step will throw an exception when it reaches one of the strings that doesn't correspond to a value of the enum.  How can I `filter` out those values so they are quietly ignored without throwing exceptions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can first encode the `Permission` enum constants into a `Set` of String and then use that in your `filter` predicate to filter out invalid values. Then use a `.map` operator to decode the enum constants back from the string representation only for valid values. Here's how it looks.

```
Set<String> strPermissionSet = Arrays.stream(Permission.values())
    .map(Permission::name)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<Permission> appPermissions = plaintextAuthorities.stream()
    .filter(strPermissionSet::contains)
    .map(Permission::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Still, you are best off declaring a static method named `isValid` in your enum type so that given a string value a user can check whether it represents a valid enum constant or not. Here's how it looks.

```
public enum Permission {
    ADMIN, USER;

    private static final Set<String> strPermissions = 
        Arrays.stream(values())
        .map(Permission::name)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    public static boolean isValid(String val) {
        return strPermissions.contains(val);
    }
}
```

And now your client code should look like this:

```
Set<Permission> appPermissions = plaintextAuthorities.stream()
    .filter(Permission::isValid)
    .map(Permission::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 5):

You could keep the names in the enum itself (as a `Map`):

```
public enum Permission {
    ADMIN,
    USER;

     static final Map<String, Permission> MAP =
        EnumSet.allOf(Permission.class)
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(
                   Enum::name,
                   Function.identity()
               ));        

}
```

And then simply do:

```
List<Permission> permissions =
        plaintextAuthorities.stream()
                            .map(Permission.MAP::get)
                            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Ravindra and Eugene posted great answers.  My own answer is less elegant and probably slower, but it does have this one advantage: I could implement it without having to modify the enum class.  In the calling class, I added a method:

```
private boolean isAValidPermission(String s) {
    try {
        Permission.valueOf(s);
        return true;
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And added one "filter" to the stream expression:

```
List<Permission> appPermissions = plaintextAuthorities.stream()
    .filter(this::isAValidPermission)
    .map(Permission::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```